# I want to break textbox value

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript to adding two textbox values and store that value in same textbox. For that process am using onmouseenter event. When i enter mouse in that textbox that textbox values increasing each time but i need to avoid it. Here i posted my code can you please solve it,

```
function removeFormField() {          
        var count_id = document.getElementById("balance").value;  
        document.getElementById('balance').value = parseInt(count_id)+10;   
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Balance amount</label> 
        <div class="col-sm-6"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="balance" name="balance" placeholder="Balance amount" onmouseenter="removeFormField();"> 
        </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried onkeypress Event?

Comment: i tried but increasing each time when i press textbox

Comment: Can you show your html code? I don't get what your trying to do.

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Balance amount</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="balance" name="balance"
                     placeholder="Balance amount" onmouseenter="removeFormField();">
                  </div>
                  </div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a flag to keep track of change

```
var allowChange = true;
function removeFormField() {          
    if(allowChange){
        var count_id = document.getElementById("balance").value;  
        document.getElementById('balance').value = parseInt(count_id)+10;
        allowChange = false;
    }   
}
```

Comment: using a flag in such a case is a basic trick. go ahead and mark the answer as correct

Comment: which event used for dropdown selection

Comment: is it related to this question?

Comment: ok for your dropdown selection, refer this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: i refered this more useful for me

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="balance" name="balance" placeholder="Balance amount" onkeypress="removeFormField()">
```

Only one change made on the input event. Changed to keypress and it is only called when you enter and input to field. and not when you click your mouse on to the field.